# How to pass dropdown value with url?

Tags: php, jquery

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#client").change(function(){
          client = $(this).val();
          $("#customer").html(client);
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>abc/ipdf/<?php echo "<p id='customer'></p>"?>" class="btn btn-danger">PDF</a>

<select name="client" id="client" class="rights">
    <option value="">Select Client</option>
    <option value="test">test</option><option value="ABC Corp">ABC Corp</option>                                    
    <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
```

In this code I have a dropdown through which I want when I change or select any value from dropdown then that value will be add with url as I mention in link tag i.e.. So, How can I do this ? please help me.

Thank You

Comment: you are using `<?php echo "<p id='customer'></p>"?>` in the `URL` and then replacing the content of that `<p>` that make no sense

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the selected value and register click event on link, where you can pass the stored value

```
<script>
var value = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#client").change(function(){
      value = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#link").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      location.href=$(this).attr("href")+value;
      return false;
    });
});
</script>

<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>abc/ipdf/" id="link" class="btn btn-danger">PDF</a>

<select name="client" id="client" class="rights">
  <option value="">Select Client</option>
  <option value="test">test</option><option value="ABC Corp">ABC Corp</option>                                    
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why override the click why not use `attr` instead to update the `href` of the `<a>` ?

Comment: if you change the href more times than one. you will need to parse the string to strip the last part (added in previous iteration). so register own click event is better approach. try to change select value two times without click on the link

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#client").change(function(){
     value = $(this).val();
     href = $("#link").attr("href");
     $("#link").attr("href",href + value);
  });  
});
</script>

<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>abc/ipdf/" id="link" class="btn btn-danger">PDF</a>

<select name="client" id="client" class="rights">
  <option value="">Select Client</option>
  <option value="test">test</option><option value="ABC Corp">ABC Corp</option>                                    
  <option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
```